# In SKE, can we assume without loss that the ciphers of a fixed plaintext distribute identically?

Tags: encryption, distinguisher

Let $(KG,D,E)$ be a symmetric encryption scheme. Fix $sk\gets KG(\lambda)$ and an arbitrary plaintext $m$.
Generally speaking, $E_{sk}$ is not deterministic, so that $E_{sk}(m)$ is a random variable, which could distribute in many different ways.

Is there a way to generically transform such a scheme to a scheme in which, for any $m$ and $sk$, $E_{sk}(m)$ distributes uniformly on its support (or at least it is indistinguishable from uniform)? Is this possible without using any cryptographic assumptions which don't already follow from the existence of an IND-CCA1 secure SKE?

Comment: I don't know any generic transformation, but there is the notion of IND$-CCA security from [here](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/nonce.pdf) which guarantees that ciphertexts are indistinguishable from uniform randomness

Comment: You might want to look into the notion of nonce-based IND\$-CPA security or nonce-based AE security which both guarantee (indist from) uniform ciphertext distribution for unique nonces. I'm not sure if there's a way to generically transform any (nonce-based) IND-CPA secure encryption scheme into a (nonce-based) IND\$-CPA secure scheme though.

Comment: Are you aware of any post quantum constructions which satisfy this notion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible without using any cryptographic assumptions which don't already follow from the existence of an IND-CCA1 secure SKE?

Yes, symmetric-key encryption implies the existence of "uniform" symmetric-key encryption. But I don't know of a particularly direct way to show it. Below is an extremely convoluted, theoretical, impractical way to do such a transformation.

1. If CPA-secure symmetric-key encryption schemes exist, then so do one-way functions. This is shown in [Impagliazzo-Luby](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=15462100418184479021&hl=en&as_sdt=0,38).
2. If one-way functions exist, then PRGs exist; this is the classic ["HILL" result](http://crypto.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Ecrepeau/COMP647/2007/TOPIC06/HILL.PDF).
3. If PRGs exist then PRFs exist; this is the classic [GGM result](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eoded/X/ggm-jacm.pdf).
4. Once you have a PRF you can construct an authenticated encryption scheme based on counter mode with a MAC like Carter-Wegman. This scheme will have the property that you need, since the ciphertext is a deterministic function of the (uniform) initialization vector + key + plaintext, and no two choices of initialization vector give the same output (since the IV is included in the output). Hence the output is uniform over the support.

Comment: Thank you, this is very valuable! Step 4. was the missing step! Do you know if this could be done post quantumly? (Zhandry has post-quantum versions of steps 1-3 so the real question, I guess, is if a qPRF implies an IND-qCPA secure encryption)

Comment: Sadly I have no clue about quantum reductions.